# How do I bind JSON to the controls?

Tags: microsoft-graph-toolkit

I am calling a graph API myself, is it possible to bind the resulting JSON to 1 of the controls? Say People? I couldn't really find how to do that in the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some components do have the ability to set the properties manually. For example, the mgt-person component accepts a json object to the `person-details` attribute (or `personDetails` property):

```
personControl.personDetails = {
    displayName: 'Nikola Metulev',
    email: 'nikola@contoso.com',
    image: 'url'
}
```

The people has the `people` property which works the same way (it's an array of persons)